# How can I make a an if statement in c# with 1 or more parameters?

Tags: c#

For example, in python an if statement can be made like this: `if example3 == 1 or example 4 == 1: print("Test")`

Is there anything equivalent in c#?

Comment: This question is not about `if` statements but about Boolean operators, which is something that any beginners tutorial would have shown you how to use.

Comment: I'd be surprised if there are many (if any) real programming languages that don't have such a construct for conditional statements. Simply searching "conditional statements" against the C# docs site produces the [Selection statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements) documentation.

Comment: @John I have not watched any tutorials, I'm just making a project and learning as I do.

Comment: Then that's your problem. The purpose of this site is not to teach you the basics. It's for the hard stuff that you cannot work out for yourself. You need to do what you can for yourself first and learning what operators the language has is well within what you can do for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the `or` operator is `||`. So something like

```
if (foo == 1 || foo == 2) {
    // do something
}
```